# httpd server not compliant because of ciphers

Tags: security, apache-httpd, ssl

I ran a security scan on a Linux Redhat server and it showed the following vulnerability:

> SSL Enabled Server Supports Medium Strength SSL Encryption Certificates/Ciphers

On the httpd.conf file I add the following ciphers:

```
SSLCipherSpec 3A
SSLCipherSpec 2F
SSLCipherSpec 35b
SSLCipherSpec 35
SSLCipherSpec 34
```

which are the shortnames for:

```
SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSLCipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSLCipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

There was also a line with the disable protocols:

```
SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2 SSLv3
```

after this I restarted the httpd and ran another scan, but the vulnerability is still there. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
> ...
> SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
> SSLCipherSpec SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
> ```

RC4 ciphers are considered weak today. Even 3DES should better not be used anymore. I recommend to follow the [recommendations by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) to properly configure your server